# moc_kviz.cpp:72: error: undefined reference to `Kviz::on_lineEdit_textChanged(QString const&)'

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, moc

This error shows me the following:

```
void Kviz::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        Kviz *_t = static_cast<Kviz *>(_o);
        Q_UNUSED(_t)
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: _t->on_lineEdit_textChanged((*reinterpret_cast< const QString(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        default: ;
        }
    }
}
```

If I delete the `switch`, `case` and the `default` it will run a few times before coming back again. I assume this error is from when I had a `lineEdit` and I fiddled with its `textChanged` slot. But, I deleted that from the UI and the relevant code and I'm not sure why its coming back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `qt_static_metacall` is automatically generated by the MOC, that should be the reason why it shows after some time.
I believe you forgot to delete `on_lineEdit_textChanged(QString const&)` from either *.c or *.h file.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I guess I'm blind and hope this question helps some other blind folks as well. Thanks